# Getting error while running Screenshotter in Firebase testLab

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to run Espresso tests on Android bundle uploaded to firebase testlab. I have also included the firebase Screenshotter library. I get the following errors in firebase test lab:

> 09-18 05:22:13.937: E/cloud_screenshotter(18993): Exception taking screenshot: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/screenshots/com.augustinus.fcmtest.LoggedInTests-haveVideoCallScreen-CallNotification-1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I already have storage permissions and this shows up at the start of logs:

```
09-18 02:51:37.784: I/GrantPermissionCallable(18946): Permission: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is already granted!
09-18 02:51:37.785: I/GrantPermissionCallable(18946): Permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is already granted!
09-18 02:51:37.785: I/GrantPermissionCallable(18946): Permission: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is already granted!
```

The device used is a physical device. Pixel 4, API Level 29

**UPDATE:**
Have tested again and can confirm the issue exists on Api level 29 but not Api Level 28. On APi Level 29 (Android 10) there have been some changes to how accessing storage works. Accessing the shared media folders is different. Very likely Firebase ScreenShotter has not been updated to cope with API level 29.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Google Firebase needs to udpate their ScreenShotter library to work with API Level 29. As a short term solution you can add the following in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```